# stopping the sign up option into devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How can I stop just anyone signing up to my application rails admin using devise?

Currently when someone goes to my domain /admin they get the opportunity to sign up.

I have all the users i need and i don't want Joe Public to be able to gain access to the backend.

it may be as simple as to change the routes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `:registerable` flag from the `User` class. (Assuming the `User` class is you Devise class, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your devise model, and you should see something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

The `devise` line is setting up which devise functionality will be included in your application. Remove the `:registerable` symbol and signup will no longer be an option.